# How to implement shake detection like shootme app?

Tags: android, shake

Now I use ShakeListener follow this [site](http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-shake-detection-listener). It works but a little more sensitive.
Does anyone know how to implement shake detection like [shootme](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bw.picme.local&feature=search_result) app ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you want the shake to be less sensitive. Using the code you posted just change the "shake time" to 250-300 ms.

```
private static final int TIME_THRESHOLD = 300;
```

Comment: You understand correct. I already test your advice and shake event has less sensitive. But It not my purpose. I need shake logic like shootme app and I try to implement it by myself now. Thanks for your answer.